# Quasar: remove shadows from a button

Tags: quasar-framework

How to remove shadows from the Quasar button which you can see when a cursor is hovering on the button and when the button is clicked?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's actually a ripple effect you are referring to.

Just add a class `no-ripple`.

It's mentioned in the [button documentation](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/button).

Answer (score 0):

It's in the [documentation](https://quasar-framework.org/components/shadows.html). Add css class `no-shadow` to disable shadow on any element/component.

Answer (score 0):

Update for 2022 is that you must use a property unelevated. Checked now for my project and it 100% works.

Full example:

```
<q-btn
            unelevated
            icon="mail"
            color="agent-fantom-theme"
            text-color="white"
            label="Search"
          />
```